# DataAttributes not Respected in WebAPI2 Unit Tests

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to learn how to properly use Unit Testing for a WebApi2 project.  In my past projects, I frequently have used DataAnnotations for basic Model validation. However, they don't seem to be triggered properly in my Unit Tests.

In the below example, the actual API controller when hit with a real HTTP request, behaves properly. It will return a BadRequest (400) when I submit a JSON object without ParrotTalk defined.  However, the TestMethod doesn't seem to invoke this rule.  What can I do to have this reflected in my Unit Test without resorting to convaluted methods?  This seems like something that should work "out of the box" as they are built in, and commonly used features in MVC.

This is my model passed up the wire in JSON.

```
 public class ParrotModel
{
    [Required]
    public string ParrotTalk { get; set; }
}
```

This is the actual method in the controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("another-endpoint")]
    public IHttpActionResult CallParrotFromBody(ParrotModel Parrot)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok(new TestModel { SomeString = "Bawwwwwk! " + Parrot.ParrotTalk });
    }
```

This is my TestMethod.  For some reason, when this runs, ModelState.IsValid is true...but it's not when running in a real site!

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CallParrotFromBody()
    {
        //good request
        var controller = new RichController();

        var result = controller.CallParrotFromBody(new ParrotModel { ParrotTalk = "Stuff" });
        OkNegotiatedContentResult<TestModel> okResult = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<TestModel>;

        Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(okResult.Content, typeof(TestModel));
        Assert.AreEqual(okResult.Content.SomeString, "Bawwwwwk! " + "Stuff" );

        //bad request---WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK????
        var nullRequestController = new RichController();
        var nullRequestResult = nullRequestController.CallParrotFromBody(new ParrotModel { });
        BadRequestResult badResult = nullRequestResult as BadRequestResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(badResult);
    }
```

In the image below, you can clearly see that the IsValid portion of the code is not triggered because the [Required] attribute wasn't processed.  This only happens when this method is called outside of a MVC application (eg: from a test).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is unit tests vs. integration tests.

The issue here is that while you are unit testing, you are testing part of the system in isolation from other components and dependencies. In your particular case it means, that while testing controller and passing model into it, parts of the application that are used for validation are not initialized and used.

In order to test whether you controller behaves correctly when there is an error within the model, you actually have to manually indicate to the controller that there is an error within the model, like so:

```
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("FieldName", "SomeError");
```

Something like this makes model invalid, so `ModelState.IsValid` in the controller will return `false`.

In case you would like to check whether actually your validation engine behaves correctly - e.g. if I pass an object with empty field which is required, will the controller return http status `400 Bad Request`?

This is actually then integration testing, which involves all the components and dependecies, linked together so get the experience similar to when you would have actually the application run on server.

There is a big difference between unit and integration testing - in unit tests you test specific parts of application in isolation, and sometimes you have to mimick behaviours and situations which in running applications are handled by other components that are initialized automatically.
In integration tests you actually test how those bits work together in an environment that is close to a real, running application.

Comment: I figured I had an XY problem, @jjczopek.  I think this is worthy of an answer, though before I do, do you have a suggestion for intergration testing in the .NET world?  I feel this is an important thing to check.